# Creating different branches of the same duplicate folder

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit

I am working on a project, and my git knowledge is basic. Trying to merge a branch to the master branch, but with different features, I want to tackle this with my basic logic (I'm seeking ease) even if it's not the best way to treat the issue.

I copied the same project folder with different names trying to create branches with features names. features all act on different files and sometimes on the same file, but I want to commit with different messages to different branches, then merge them one by one with the master branch.

The first challenge, is why I go to different folders, I get the same branch name. Can I just rename the branch based on features.

Is this a valid workflow ?

Comment: Do you have a server set up or do you want to do it all locally on your computer?

Comment: I'm on Github entreprise battlmonstr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In git it is not common to create copies of the folder to work on different features, because the branching is so lightweight, and it is easy to switch branches inside a single folder.

Nevertheless if the project is big, complicated to setup, or each feature requires a lot of external configuration to test, it might be easier to work in separate folders.

For git each folder is a separate repository, so suppose you have folders for features X, Y and the github repo G, then it means that you have actually 3 separate repos: X, Y and G.

One way to do what you want would be to first prepare the feature repo X as you want, and sync it with G using git pull/push. Then you prepare the feature repo Y and sync that with G as well.

In the end you still gonna have 3 separate repos, but each will have branches feature-x, feature-y and master having identical commits.

So if you are in the folder X to create a branch "feature-x" from the current state and switch to that you would use:

```
git checkout -b feature-x
```

I suppose that you have already made your commits and `git log` looks fine.

Then you sync with "G" by doing `git push`. That will add the branch `feature-x` and your new commits to G.

At this point you can actually go to github and create a pull request that can be merged to master via the web interface.

If you don't want to do it via the pull request web UI, then you just first prepare your master branch in folder X locally to the state you want, where the easiest is:

```
git checkout master
git merge feature-x
```

And then you sync the master branch of X and G using `git push`.

Finally repeat the same process for Y and other features.

Note: the first thing to do in feature repo Y is to get the new state of master branch from github repo G, you do that by `git pull`.

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

Make sure that your master in Y is not changed at this point, because otherwise it will merge the G state of master on top of the Y state of master. `git fetch` is an alternative to `git pull` that doesn't do the merge.

If it was changed, to backup your state without switching the branch do `git branch feature-y`, and restore the master to original state by `git reset --hard origin/master`. Then it is safe to do `git pull`.

Comment: This is so complete, and fully satisfying my question, I will recheck it step by step, to attain what I'm aiming to. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome. I was afraid that it's too wordy. :)